# Mapping over a dictionary to display dropdown values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm really new to Javascript and the whole idea of functional programming. Thus the question. So I have a dropdown menu as a React Component,

```
class Dropdown extends React.Component{

  render(){
    return(
        <SplitButton title="Dropdown">
          <MenuItem href="#books">Books</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem href="#podcasts">Podcasts</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem href="#">Tech I Like</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem href="#">About me</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem href="#addBlog">Add a Blog</MenuItem>
        </SplitButton>
    );
}
```

I want to replace the hardcoded values with values from a hashMap and get something like this.

```
render(){
<SplitButton title={chosenKey}>
   {dict.map(this.displayOptions)}
</SplitButton>
}
```

This is the displayOptions function,

```
displayOptions(){
    return(
      <MenuItem href="#" onClick={this.onDropDownClick}>{}</MenuItem>
    );
  }
```

Which I'm not able to get right, here's what I'm trying to do.
Display the Key of the hashMap, but on click capture the value. This is my hashMap,

```
const dict = {
  "A" : "123",
  "B" : "234",
  "C": "345",
  "D": "456",
  "E": "567",
  "F": "678",
  "G" : "789"

};
```

Would really appreciate some `Black Friday` help with this.

Comment: Your "hashmap" isn't a hash map, it's an object. (This is more important than it used to be, as JavaScript now has a `Map` class.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a very simple example that uses `Object.keys` to map over your `dict` object:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      dict: {
        "A" : "123",
        "B" : "234",
        "C": "345",
        "D": "456",
        "E": "567",
        "F": "678",
        "G" : "789"
      }
    };
  }
  
  onClick(value) {
    console.log(value);  
  }

  render() {
    const dict = this.state.dict;
    return (
      <ul>
        {Object.keys(dict).map(key => (
         <li>
           <a
             href={`#${dict[key]}`}
             onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, dict[key])}
             key={key}>
             {key}
           </a>
         </li>))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="View"></div>
```

Comment: This does solve the first part of the problem, could you help with capturing the value inside the `onDropDownClick`

Comment: Not sure if I understand what your goal is. Updated my answer. Does that help?

Comment: Yup it does. Thanks.